# How block or break access to the database inside controller (to test conditions)

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible to block or break access to the database inside controller instead of TODO ? I want go to line "return response('',201);"

```
public function updateLike(Request $request){
    $comment = Comment::find($request->id);
    // TODO: block or break access to the database here
    if ($comment -> save()){
        return response('',200);
    } else {
        return response('',201);
    }
}
```

Comment: what you want to do is not clear ?

Comment: I suggest you using try catch since is very useful to prevent ppl from doing stupid things!

Comment: I don't realy understand what you are after ether. If you want to prevent the user to save anything at all, maybe it is a good idea to use Policies. You can read about it in the laravel docs under 'security'. You can write your logic here if a user is allowed to do something, and then you can call this logic inside your controller function. If you want authorization over entire controllers or route groups, I suggest you read up on route Middleware.

Comment: In other words: I want to test situation when access to the DB is broken when php-code executing between rows **$comment=...** and **if ($comment...**. I need it for onetime testing to understand how works **save()** method when it is impossible to save data to db.

Comment: @Jurchello you mean dd($comment)?